# How can I change the color of the comments in Code::Blocks?

Tags: codeblocks

The comments in the Code::Blocks IDE are difficult to see because their color is too light. How can I change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu: Settings/Editor...
Syntax highlighting
Comments

There are several different "Comments" entries, play around to find the one you need.